# Contact resistance copper-silver

Tags: measurements, electrical-resistance

I need to determine the contact resistance of a copper silver interface.
The copper wire was soldered to the substrate using an IR-Laser.
I was wondering if  I can treat the entire system as a series of three resistors (wire, interface, substrate), so I can measure the resistance between wire and substrate using four terminal sensing and then subtract the resistance of the appropriate lengths of wire and substrate alone and be left with the contact resistance.

Comment: You'll also have contact resistance between your ohmmeter and the copper wire, and between your ohmmeter and your silver substrate.  All of these resistances will be teeny-tiny and comparable in size, so by subtracting you run the risk of catastrophic cancellation. Can you elaborate on why you want just the interface resistance, rather than the easier-to-measure resistance of your wire, junction, and substrate as a lumped element? That might suggest a technique to isolate the quantity you want.

Comment: It's a thing I need to do for my Bachelor thesis. I thought using four terminal sensing eliminates the contact resistance between the tips and the object I'm measuring.

Comment: Your bachelor thesis surely isn't called "resistance of a copper-silver interface." What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: I need to study the effect of different elements and surface geometries on the contact resistance. That's pretty much it.